# Can push in connectors be used for parallel circuits?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, circuit

Adding in new construction can lights that come with push in connectors.

Rather than using the old yellow cap twists, the connectors have 4 slots and I wanted to know if I can just run a line from one light to the next using these connectors, or will that act as series?

Comment: Is this 14AWG or 12AWG, and how big are the boxes on these can lights?

Comment: 12AWG, boxes are about 3x5 with roughly 6 punch outs. Only one wire will come in and one wire out. I was just unsure if these push in connectors are supplemental for splicing a line and using a twist.

Comment: Are the boxes *marked* with a volume though?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel not that I can see, but each push in connection has 4 slots (all 3 wires). Assuming there is no volume issue, the question is whether or not these push in connectors are analogous of the older twist caps.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel [these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-H7-6-in-Aluminum-Recessed-Lighting-Housing-for-New-Construction-Ceiling-Insulation-Contact-H7ICT/203891777?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&mtc=Shopping-B-F_D27L-G-D27L-27_13_RECESSED_LIGHTING-NA-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-RECESSED_LIGHTING_InteriorRecessedLighting&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D27L-G-D27L-27_13_RECESSED_LIGHTING-NA-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-RECESSED_LIGHTING_InteriorRecessedLighting-71700000052687882-58700005047732054-92700052328522614&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIj5fuvueU7QIVBopaBR1MQgSpEAQYASABEgKex_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) are the assemblies I am working with.

Comment: Wago push in splices may be rated for 12 awg wire I do not use them on anything other than low wattage fixtures like fluorescent or LED conversions but yes they can be used, most that have had wire nut problems in the past are internet only electricians as the types that had failures are well over 40 years back there have been no changes in the ideal or 3m brands other than color coding in the case of scotch locks , most of the failures were with aluminum wire and alumiconns were invented to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

"old yellow cap twists" - if you hate the things then use something else.

However you *should* hate the **old** ones. Old wire-nuts aren't very good, or to be more precise, newer ones are *better designed*.  I throw away all old wire nuts especially Scotchloks.

The other reason to hate wire-nuts is if you have not learned proper technique.   If they don't firmly hold together by themselves, you're not tightening them enough, or wrong-size nut for that many wires.  I stock yellow and red, that covers just about everything.

Never, ever tape wire nuts. Or to be more precise, never ***need to*** tape wire nuts. A proper splice must easily pass a "pull test" (hold nut, yank each wire one at a time).

"Backstab" connections on receptacles and switches are known to be unreliable.  Some here will vouch for the stabby splice, but keep in mind those "came free with the lights" which isn't the highest recommendation in the world.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you connect white to white and black to black you will have a parallel circuit.

only thing to watch out for is how many lights you string together.
your circuit may already be overloaded.

if you have about 12 to 16 lights on a circuit you should not add anymore.

[image]

Comment: Circuit is 6 at most

Comment: You can easily run **120** (10W LED) fixtures without overloading a 15A circuit. Beware the rule of thumb that may be out of date.

Comment: @Ecnerwal tell that to an inspector. any type of light may be installed in the future. you can't assume it will always be LED.